# How can i setup a base drawer for all activities

Tags: java, android, listview, android-activity

I have read a lot of answers here but could not manage to do it. I want all of my activities to have a drawer. Inside the drawer i have a `ListView` which contains all of the activities that the drawer should open. This is the implementation of the drawer:

```
public abstract class DrawerActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView drawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.base_drawer_layout);
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        drawerList = findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        final ArrayList<String> elements = new ArrayList<>();
        elements.add("My tasks");
        elements.add("Issues");

        drawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, elements));
        drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(createOnDrawerItemClickListener());

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                drawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
            {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("TITLE");
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
            {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
            return true;

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    protected abstract DrawerItemClickListener createOnDrawerItemClickListener();

    protected ListView drawerList()
    {
        return drawerList;
    }

    protected DrawerLayout drawerLayout()
    {
        return drawerLayout;
    }

}
```

This is the drawer layout xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#274"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Lets say i have currently two activities, My Tasks and Issues and both of them extend `DrawerActivity`. If i am in the Issues activity, how can i open the My Tasks activity through that drawer?

All activities that extend DrawerActivity implements createOnDrawerItemClickListener() which inside creates a new fragment with the layout of the the activity that implements DrawerActivity, which i'm pretty sure is wrong.

Example implementation:

```
@Override
protected DrawerItemClickListener createOnDrawerItemClickListener()
{
    return new DrawerItemClickListener(position ->
    {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new TaskFragment()).commit();
        drawerList().setItemChecked(position, true);
        drawerLayout().closeDrawer(drawerList());
    });
}
```

And the DrawerItemClickListener:

```
public class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

    private FragmentStrategy fragmentStrategy;

    public DrawerItemClickListener(final FragmentStrategy fragmentStrategy)
    {
        this.fragmentStrategy = fragmentStrategy;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        fragmentStrategy.showFragment(position);
    }

    public interface FragmentStrategy {

        void showFragment(final int position);

    }
}
```

How can i make this work?

Comment: If you want all screens having drawer, best approach will be using fragments in single activity instead of setting drawer in all activities. It takes 5 minutes to convert your activity to fragment.

Comment: I am not very familiar with Android, how would i do that?

Comment: You want i tell to convert activity to fragment or method to add fragment in activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case adding fragment will be the best solution.

create a fragment BlankFragment.java

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    }

}
```

and create fragment_black.xml

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.above_inc.shyam.drawer.BlankFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

now replace your method

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    Fragment fragment = null;
    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
        fragment = new BlankFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;

}
```

add below code in your content_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.above_inc.shyam.drawer.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

you can also add more fragment to other options same as camera in above code